# Can't restart the While Loop in Python

Tags: python-3.x

SO the program is not running as I want it to be. If the user type 1 or 2, the output repeats
 "nvm"
"wanna try again"
just this whatever I type. Please Help!!!

```
import random
guess = input("Whats your guess")
comp = random.randrange(0, 10)
print(comp)
guess_correct = True
while guess_correct == True:
    if guess == comp:
        print("Bullseye!!!!!")
    else:
        print("nvm")

    ask = int(input("Wanna try again?If yes type 1, if no type 2"))
    if ask == 1:
        guess_correct = True
    elif ask == 2:
        guess_correct = False
```

Comment: you should try to make your guess input inside the while loop ...

Answer (score 0):

With the guess input **inside the loop** we can simply write :

```
import random
comp = random.randrange(0, 10)
print(comp)
guess_correct = True
while guess_correct:
    guess = int(input("Whats your guess ? "))
    if guess == comp:
        print("Bullseye!!!!!")
        guess_correct = False
    else:
        print("nvm")
        ask = int(input("Wanna try again?If yes type 1, if no type 2 "))
        if ask == 2:
            guess_correct = False
```

Also don't forget to cast the input to an *int* and if it's the correct answer it's useless to ask for an other try ...